# convert vba date function to sql

Tags: sql, teradata

I need help converting the following vba code to a similar SQL string.

```
    vDt = Now()
    vStartDate = UCase(Format(DateSerial(Year(vDt), Month(vDt) - 1, 1), "DD-MMM-YYYY"))
    vEndDate = UCase(Format(DateSerial(Year(vDt), Month(vDt), 0), "DD-MMM-YYYY"))
```

Comment: Using which SQL and what have you tried so far?

Comment: Using Teradata SQL Assistant and have not tried anything yet.

Comment: Ok, and what's your input i.e. how do you get this date originally? As a datetime/string, what format? What's expected output - string of format: "dd-MmMM-yyyy" ?

Comment: The date is retrieved from a variable vDt which houses the current date.

Comment: What's the format of variable ```vDt```? Can you share example of it?

Comment: Format is as follows 12/30/2019

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding this correctly, you want the start date to be the first day of the previous month and the end date to be the last day of the current month.  Then you want to convert them to the date format DD-MMM-YYYY.  If so, below would be the corresponding SQL:

```
DECLARE @now DATETIME;
DECLARE @start DATETIME;
DECLARE @end DATETIME;
SET @now = GETDATE();
SET @start = DATEADD(MONTH, -1, DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, @now), 0));
SET @end = EOMONTH(@now);

SELECT UPPER(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), @start, 106), ' ', '-')) AS StartDate,
    UPPER(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), @end, 106), ' ', '-')) AS EndDate;
```

EDIT - Sorry I should mention that this is in Microsoft T-SQL and not Teradata SQL Assistant (thank you @a_horse_with_no_name).  I'm not familiar with Teradata so I can't give you the exact answer, however I believe you can find similar functions to translate the above answer.

Comment: You should have mentioned that this is T-SQL (for Microsoft SQL Server) not "SQL"

Answer (score 0):

In Teradata SQL you get the 1st day of the previous month using

```
 Trunc(Add_Months(Current_Date, -1), 'mon')
```

and the last day of the current month:

```
Last_Day(Current_Date)
```

Of course this returns a data, if you want a `DD-MMM-YYYY` string:

```
SELECT
   To_Char(Trunc(Add_Months(Current_Date, -1), 'MON'), 'DD-MON-YYYY')
  ,To_Char(Last_Day(Current_Date), 'DD-MON-YYYY')
```